# JavaFX Set Accelerator inside Event Handler does not Work?

Tags: java, debugging, javafx, event-handling

Apologies ahead for the long backstory. But I think it is necessary for you to understand my intentions and understand the bug.

---

So here it is: I have a JavaFX GUI that contains a button. My intention is that by right-clicking the button, the user can bring up a context menu, at which point they can use a single keystroke to trigger a menu item. So I this is my `start()` method:

```
    FlowPane root = new FlowPane();
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 100);

    Button btn = new Button("Test");

    // Add context menu and define actions.
    ContextMenu cM = new ContextMenu();

    MenuItem mI0 = new MenuItem("First");
    mI0.setOnAction(aE ->
    {
        System.out.println("First Action");
        cM.hide();
    });
    MenuItem mI1 = new MenuItem("Second");
    mI1.setOnAction(aE ->
    {
        System.out.println("Second Action");
        cM.hide();
    });
    cM.getItems().addAll(mI0, mI1);

    // Set accelerators.
    mI0.setAccelerator(new KeyCodeCombination(KeyCode.F));
    mI1.setAccelerator(new KeyCodeCombination(KeyCode.S));

    btn.setContextMenu(cM);

    root.getChildren.add(btn);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
```

This works fine. I can right click on the button, type `f` or `s` and the corresponding text would print. All is well for now.

---

But in my GUI I actually have several of these buttons, each representing an executable and having their own context menu. The items in their context menus are "Run" and "Run with Parameters", and triggering them should run that specific executable. So my code turns into this. For simplicity's sake I'm using fruits as an analogy.

```
    FlowPane root = new FlowPane();
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 100);

    String[] buttonNames = { "Apple", "Pear", "Orange" };
    for (String s : buttonNames)
    {
        Button btn = new Button(s);

        // Add context menu and define actions.
        ContextMenu cM = new ContextMenu();

        MenuItem mI0 = new MenuItem("Eat");
        mI0.setOnAction(aE ->
        {
            System.out.println("Eat " + btn.getText());
            cM.hide();
        });
        MenuItem mI1 = new MenuItem("Cut");
        mI1.setOnAction(aE ->
        {
            System.out.println("Cut " + btn.getText());
            cM.hide();
        });
        cM.getItems().addAll(mI0, mI1);

        // Set accelerators.
        mI0.setAccelerator(new KeyCodeCombination(KeyCode.E));
        mI1.setAccelerator(new KeyCodeCombination(KeyCode.C));

        btn.setContextMenu(cM);

        root.getChildren().add(btn);
    }

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
```

Now if you are vigilant you probably noticed the problem right away. The accelerators are set for the scene, so even when the context menu isn't showing, pressing `e` or `c` on keyboard triggers. Even worse, the only fruit eaten or cut now is orange since its accelerator has overwritten that of the apple and pear.

---

So my solution to this is as follows. Set the accelerators when the context menu is shown and remove them when it's hidden. Sounds easy.

```
    FlowPane root = new FlowPane();
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 100);

    String[] buttonNames = { "Apple", "Pear", "Orange" };
    for (String s : buttonNames)
    {
        Button btn = new Button(s);

        // Add context menu and define actions.
        ContextMenu cM = new ContextMenu();

        MenuItem mI0 = new MenuItem("Eat");
        mI0.setOnAction(aE ->
        {
            System.out.println("Eat " + btn.getText());
            cM.hide();
        });
        MenuItem mI1 = new MenuItem("Cut");
        mI1.setOnAction(aE ->
        {
            System.out.println("Cut " + btn.getText());
            cM.hide();
        });
        cM.getItems().addAll(mI0, mI1);

        // Set accelerator on context menu show.
        cM.setOnShown(wE ->
        {
            mI0.setAccelerator(new KeyCodeCombination(KeyCode.E));
            mI1.setAccelerator(new KeyCodeCombination(KeyCode.C));
            System.out.println("Accelerators set for " + btn.getText());
        });
        // Remove accelerator on context menu hide.
        cM.setOnHiding(wE ->
        {
            cM.getItems().forEach(mI -> mI.setAccelerator(null));
            System.out.println("Accelerators removed for " + btn.getText());
        });

        btn.setContextMenu(cM);

        root.getChildren().add(btn);
    }

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
```

No reason for this to not work. When using mouse only it seems to be working:

[image][image][image]

But when I press `e` or `c` instead after opening context menu, this happens:

[image]

(Press `e`)

[image]

Nothing happens.

---

Now you can clearly see that the lines of code setting and removing accelerator did run. The `E` and `C` next to `Eat` and `Cut` in the menu indicate their corresponding accelerators are set, and the console printout confirms this. But for some reason the accelerators are not responding to my key presses.

Can someone tell me why and potentially how to solve this?

Comment: I suspect (though I'm not sure) that what happens is that the accelerators are registered to the Scene only once when the `ContextMenu` is assigned (or the node is added to the scene graph), and so changing them after the fact won't have the desired effect. You can look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34008793/javafx-tabpane-context-menu-depending-on-selected-tab) for a different approach to a very similar problem, or use filters as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31732583/pass-context-menu-shortcuts-up-from-editing-control)

Comment: @Itai Thanks for the suggestion. I think you are correct. Changing my first segment of code so that accelerators are set after `root.getChildren.add(btn);` breaks it. I will try the `onContextMenuRequested` method.