# Application wide key listener

Tags: java, javafx

I want to register an application wide key listener. I know, that i can register an key listener for a node. But if this node dont have the current focus, the listener is not thrown. In my current application i have an anchorpane on top of this i have an grid pane with different panes and tableviews. So now i want that the user can press "F5" to refresh the current view. But if the focus is on some textfield, the key press is not thrown. Is there a way to register an listener to the whole application?

Comment: Possible duplicate / related question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31732583/pass-context-menu-shortcuts-up-from-editing-control

How I solved it is by registering a KeyHandler on the root node.

Comment: Yes thank you. Solved my problem. But it seems that it is a workaround and not an solution, right?

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate / related question - [Application wide key listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34788337/application-wide-key-listener/34791477#34791477) How I solved it is by registering a KeyHandler on the root node.